# hls video: Why is there a difference between segment length and target duration?

Tags: http-live-streaming, duration, segment

I am trying to prepare the files for a hls video.
As player I am using video.js and I am transcoding my content with ffmpeg into multiple streams of different size and bitrate.
I tried a lot of options but mainly I kept framerate and bitrate constant and produced iframes every second as I want to have 3s segments.

Then I segmented the streams with mp4hls and processed the playlists.

It seems to work all perfectly, the playlists are correct, the iframes also, but:

The length of the segments is 2 seconds and not like expected 3 seconds?

```
something like: 
...-b:v: 192k -bufsize 200k -maxrate 192k -r 30 -g 30 -x264opts no-scenecut
```

and in python: 
    mp4hls --segment-duration 3 320x180.mp4 
    480x270.mp4 
    640x360.mp4 
....

I would like to know if there is somewhere an error in my workflow
or if  this is correct as I read in the hls specifications
that the segment must be equal or smaller than the #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
Can somebody please explain to a beginner, why the segments are not the same 
length than
written in the playlist. I could find nothing about this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All segments don’t need to the same duration. The target duration is just a hint as to how often the player should expect a manifest update.

Comment: That means, that the player does not need any segmentation, he only follows the instructions of the playlist? But why do we split the file in chunks then?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always a framerate issue. It looks like you’re using FFMPEG. It has default settings for scene-cut and works out its own keyframes.. Therefore, you need to set this explicitly if you want specifically timed segments. Off the top of my head you need to set GOP, and Keyframe values.. Something like:

```
-g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0
```

Will give you a strict 2 second segment with a 30fps input